# Detach command from SSH session

Tags: ssh, process, sh, remote-server

I need to run commands on a server via an SSH session and close the session without killing the process on the server. How can this be implemented correctly.

Server and client are linux systems.

Please note than I can't install additional software on server.

Comment: I can't install additional software on server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Before using special tools

1. #### Undertanding

   Why do ssh not return when I try to background job on target.

   ```
   ssh user@host 'sleep 300 &'
   ```

   Then you have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to get your session.

   This is because each connection hold 3 *file descriptors*: *`STDIN (0)`*, *`STDOUT (1)`* and *`STDERR (2)`*. The connection will **stay open** while at least one of this *file descriptors* are ***in use***.
2. #### Simply closing them  before running background task

   This is aproximatively what `nohup` do.

   ```
   ssh user@host 'exec 0<&-;exec 1>&-;exec 2>&-; sleep 300 &'
   ```

   This will do the job.

   ##### Or by using `nohup`:

   ```
   ssh user@host 'nohup sleep 300 &'
   ```

   Will do the job too.
3. #### Redirecting output to static file(s)

   You could store output in files located somewhere on server side:

   ```
   ssh user@host 'exec 0<&-;exec 1>>/path/to/logfile;exec 2>>/path/to/errlog; sleep 300 &'
   ```

   `>>` for adding log to existing files... you could use uniq files by adding `$$`  or `date +%F`...

   ```
   ssh user@host 'exec 0<&-;exec 1>/path/to/logfile-$$;exec 2>&1; sleep 300 &'
   ```

   `2>&1` cited **after** `1>file` will redirect `STDERR` as `STDOUT` to `file`.

   ```
   ssh user@host 'exec 0<&-;exec 1>/path/to/file-$(date +%F-%T).$$;exec 2>&-;sleep 300 &'
   ```

   Only `STDOUT` will be stored in newfiles.

### Using `screen`

4. #### If `screen` is installed

   If you would be able to access interactive front end, you could:

   ```
   ssh user@host screen -dmS mySleep sh -c \
             "'x=0;while [ \$x -lt 300 ];do echo \$x;x=\$((x+1));sleep 1;done'"
   ```

   This will start a background job, printing 1 ling each 300 next second, then finish.

   To reconnect this, you could

   ```
   ssh -t user@host screen -x mySleep
   ```

   Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, followed by <kbd>d</kbd> for leaving background task.
5. #### Installing `screen` at *`user`* level

   If you can't install something in server, maybe* could you
   install something in your `$HOME` directory:

   (* This will be easy if your architecture is same than on server. If not, you even could find compatible binaries or cross compile yourself.)

   ```
    $ ssh user@host
    user@host:~$ mkdir bin lib
    user@host:~$ exit
    $ scp /path/to/bin/screen user@host:~/bin
    $ ssh user@host
    user@host:~$ bin/screen
    bin/screen: error while loading shared libraries: libutempter.so.0:
              cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    user@host:~$ exit
    $ scp /path/to/lib/libutempter.so.0 user@host:~/lib
    $ ssh user@host
    user@host:~$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/lib bin/screen
    bin/screen: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1: version `XCRYPT_2.0' 
              not found (required by bin/screen)
    user@host:~$ exit
    $ scp /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1  user@host:~/lib
    $ ssh user@host
    user@host:~$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/lib bin/screen
    Cannot make directory '/run/screen': Permission denied
    user@host:~$ mkdir $HOME/.screen
    user@host:~$ SCREENDIR=$HOME/.screen LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/lib bin/screen
   ```

   Finally, now it work...

   ```
    $ ssh user@host SCREENDIR=\~/.screen LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\~/lib bin/screen -dmS mySleep sh -c \
             "'x=0;while [ \$x -lt 300 ];do echo \$x;x=\$((x+1));sleep 1;done'"
    $ ssh -t user@host SCREENDIR=\~/.screen LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\~/lib bin/screen -x mySleep
   ```

There are lot of other alternatives, like `tmux`, `byobu`...

Upto create your own wrapper...

Answer (score 5):

`nohup` is the best tool for this, in my opinion.

Simply use it like:

```
nohup command &
```

As taken from [nohup's man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup):

> If standard input is a terminal, redirect it from /dev/null. If
> standard output is a terminal, append output to 'nohup.out' if
> possible, '$HOME/nohup.out' otherwise. If standard error is a
> terminal, redirect it to standard output. To save output to FILE, use
> 'nohup COMMAND > FILE'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `screen` or `tmux` utilities for this, if one is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [reptyr](https://linux.die.net/man/1/reptyr). It is  a utility for taking an existing running program and attaching it to a new terminal. You just need to start a screen, use `reptyr` to grab it, and then kill the ssh session. `reptyr`  works  by attaching to the target program using `ptrace(2)`, redirecting relevant file descriptors, and changing the program's controlling terminal. After attaching a program, the program will appear to be either backgrounded or suspended to the shell it was launched from (depending on
the shell). It is preferable to use `bg; disown` in  the  old  shell to remove the association with the program, but `reptyr` will attempt to ensure that the target program remains running
even if you close the shell without doing so.

Comment: I don't have permission to install new software on the server. If it comes by default I'll try it out.