# How to implement a very simple file-based notification queue using bash?

Tags: bash, concurrency, notifications, queue

I'm trying to come up with a very simple implementation for this problem:

- I have 2 environments behaving under a master-slave paradigm
- `Environment A` manages `environment B`: configures it, runs scripts in it, etc.
- `Environment B` cannot initiate communications with `environment A`
- Sometimes `environment A` leaves scripts running in `environment B`'s background [`./myScript.sh &`], and has no way of knowing when those scripts are finished (well, `environment A` could just poll `B` with `ps -aux`, but I'm looking for a more generic system)

I'd like to create a system that satisfies these conditions:

- When a background script `myScript.sh` finishes, it leaves a message in some mailbox
- `Environment A` keeps a runner that periodically checks the mailbox in environment B, and *consumes* all new messages
- Adding and consuming messages to this 'queue' must be resistant to race conditions / concurrency
- The solution must be based on Bash

I thought of 2 options:

- Option A: modeling the mailbox as a file. `myScript.sh` appends notifications to the file; `environment A` reads and empties the file via ssh. I guess race conditions could be solved via file locking? I think bash allows this.
- Option B: much simpler, `myScript.sh` would leave messages as separate files in a well-known folder which would act as mailbox. `Environment A` would get the list of files, `cat` them and remove them.

But perhaps the vast know-how of StackOverflow will propose must better / simpler options.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you already try something? Please share you're code

Comment: Machine B: use `echo >>/path/to/logfile "Process $id ended."`, then from machime A: `ssh machineB tail -f  /path/to/logfile` in a ***subtask***! See [Detach command from SSH session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70723607/1765658), [How to run ssh in background while keeping access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21522587/1765658) and [Sample using `ssh machine tail -f ...`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73217493/1765658)... And maybe: [How to 'grep' a continuous stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70517999/1765658)

Comment: Do both "environments" run on the same host?